# Cannot respond to ARP requests in OVS system

Tags: arp, openvswitch

In my environment I have two Linux hosts, 1 and 2. They try to communicate with one another and 1 has an openvswitch running.

[image]

Before adding the OVS bridge, the host 1 and host 2 could communicate successfully. However, after adding br0 (and eth2 as port), **ARP requests from 193.168.1.11 to 193.168.1.1 never get a response**.

First of all, notice that the br0 of host1 cannot have the same IP as the eth2, as it is required for eth2 to have a "public" ip address that is given by a DHCP server I do not control. For this question, I assumed br0's IP address is 20.0.1.1.

I configured the bridge like this:

```
$ ovs-vsctl add-br br0
$ ovs-vsctl add-port br0 eth2
```

and now, packets from 193.168.1.11 arrive at br0 (as seen on tcpdump).

Then, I added the flow entry:

```
$ ovs-ofctl -O openflow13 br0 priority=1,arp,in_port=eth2,action=output:NORMAL
```

which did not solve the problem, and then:

```
$ ovs-ofctl -O openflow13 br0 priority=1,arp,nw_src=193.168.1.0/24,action=output:NORMAL
```

still no response...

The ARP flow entry is the only one currently installed. How can I make ARP responses work?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you can't tell `br0` to take its address from the DHCP and remove `eth2` from the equation...?

Comment: Well, the host 1 in my diagram is actually a router with an antenna to a 3G broadband cellular network. Thus, "eth2" gets its IP address from that same cellular network (and I have no control over it). This happens when I insert the SIM card into the slot and an interface called "3g0" becomes active. I thought that, by manually removing the IP address of "eth2" (that is, 3g0 in the router), it would be impossible for br0 to get and IP from the cellular network (since it is not associated with the NIC of the antenna). Am I wrong?

Comment: I think you need to update your interfaces' configurations to set `eth2` as static and tell `br0` to take its IP from the DHCP. You can do that via the GUI (if there's one) or by editing `/etc/network/interfaces`.

Comment: So, if br0 assumed eth2's MAC address and I changed it to "iface br0 inet dhcp" in /etc/network/interfaces, and configured eth2 as "iface eth2 inet static", would br0 still be able to **automatically** get an IP address from the cellular network? Assuming that the IP assigned may vary with time, depending on which mobile network carrier it is connected to, for instance (the router is in a bus, so it changes location frequently).

Comment: Since it would be relying on the DHCP server to allocate that address, yes.

Comment: I appreciate your help very much. I will make the modifications right away.

Comment: Please let me know if that solves the issue. I can make a proper answer to help others in that case.

Comment: I realized that even if I have an isolated bridge like in my diagram, I can still receive the packets from host 2. Giving eth2's IP and MAC to br0 also solves the problem, like stated above.